# regex to do multi line search in eclipse

Tags: regex, unix, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I need a regular expression to match only the comment before the line containing "private final VARIABLE".

**INPUT:**

```
/**
*okay1
*/
menu
/**
*  okay2.
*/
private final VARIABLE;
```

OUTPUT should be :

```
/**
*  okay2.
*/
private final VARIABLE;
```

The strings okay1 and okay2 could be anything. They represent comments here. I tried doing this which does not work.

```
 ((\/\*\*[\S\s]*\*\/){1})[\s]*(private\s*final\s*VARIABLE\;)
```

This matches the first comment as well (okay1) which I dont want. I am familiar with regex but this is something not straightforward. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/\s*(private\s+final\s+VARIABLE;)
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/FdrN4Y/1/)

**Details**

- `/\*+` - match the comment start, `/*` and any 0+ asterisks after it
- `[^*]*\*+` - match 0+ characters other than `*` followed with 1+ literal `*`
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - not a `/` or `*` (matched with `[^/*]`) followed with 0+ non-asterisk characters (`[^*]*`) followed with 1+ asterisks (`\*+`)
- `/` - closing `/`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(private\s+final\s+VARIABLE;)` - Group 1: `private`, 1+ whitespaces, `final`, 1+ whitespaces, `VARIABLE;`.

Comment: how do I also include space or tabs which might be present before the start of comment /**

Comment: @Zack `\s*` will match any 0 or more whitespace chars.

Comment: I want to replace only the whitespace preceding the comment on the same line. If I use \s+, it goes to preceding lines until it matches all the whitespaces and \n

Comment: @Zack So, you want to only match horizontal whitespaces. You have lots of options: `\h*`, `[\p{Zs}\t]*`, `[^\S\r\n]*`, `[ \t]*`, etc. Choose the one that suits you best.